# How to share Robot Framework __init__.robot library initialization state with test cases?

Tags: python, robotframework

Suppose I have a Robot library implemented in python that does some state initialization like this:

```py
import uuid

class DemoLibrary:

    ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'SUITE'

    _my_uuid: str

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._my_uuid = str(uuid.uuid4())

    def get_library_uuid(self) -> str:
        return self._my_uuid
```

And within an `__init__.robot` file I initialize that library:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  DemoLibrary

Suite Setup  Set Up Suite

*** Keywords ***
Set Up Suite
    ${lib_uuid}  Get Library Uuid
    Set Global Variable  ${GLOBAL_UUID}  ${lib_uuid}
```

If I then try to use that library in a test case in the suite defined by the `__init__.robot` file the library is re-initialized:

`a_test.robot`:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  DemoLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
Setup Proof Of Concept
    ${lib_uuid}  Get Library UUID
    Should Be Equal  ${GLOBAL_UUID}  ${lib_uuid}
```

^ This fails with `[FAIL] 9854fe14-47e5-4484-92c6-930a5cc5224c != d81635d0-0716-487f-9a22-1a450499652e` (obviously, with unique uuids each time)

If I log the object ids of self from the python library I can also see that they change between the keyword invocations.

My directory structure looks like this:

```
demo
└── a_test/
    ├── __init__.robot
    └── a_test.robot
    libraries/
    └── DemoLibrary.py
```

I'm invoking the from demo with `robot --pythonpath=libraries a_test/`.

I've tried various combinations of `WITH NAME`, `Import Library` and `Get Library Instance` but none of them seemed to work.

Is there a way reuse or share the instance of the library created in `__init__.robot`?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer is that suite initialization files do not provide imports or variables down to rest of the suite files, so what you are trying to achieve here will not work.

Long answer is that you can share library state between suites by first defining the library as `'GLOBAL'` on the `ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE` line to prevent a new instance being created for each test suite you run. This will make it so that each test suite run in the same session will use the same library instance. Notice however that if your library requires arguments, giving new arguments will force a new instance to be created always. There's more info about library scope in the [Robot Framework User Guide](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#library-scope).

When sharing properties between test suites it is usually good idea to use a [resource file](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#resource-files). This helps when your shared library requires arguments - If you provide different argument value to the library import it will *always* create a new instance. Using resource files is also generally a good practice.

To use a resource file for the import add a new file `resources.robot` to your project and import the library there. When using the resource file in the test suite files later, the resource file only imports the library once.

Comment: When you said "and by importing the library in a resource file instead" do you mean that if the library is defined as `'GLOBAL'` but is not imported from a resource file, it will still create multiple instances?

Comment: @nine9ths Pretty sure it will be imported once, but in general I support idea of loading resource that loads library. In such case it's clear what import arguments are used and you need to change them in one place if needed.

Comment: @nine9ths It does not create a new instance if you have the scope defined correctly. Just usually good practice that I should've explained more clearly. But notice that adding new argument when importing *will* create a new library instance.